# Descargar archivo PDF guardado, descargar con el nombre de file grabado

Tags: php, laravel, livewire

quiero descargar un archivo pdf de un sistema desarrollado con laravel y livewire.
Para explicarme bien, cargo un pdf y lo registro con su respectivo nombre y el nombre que genera las funciones de laravel. Dejo codigo abajo:

archivo pdf grabado:  2022-05/PpS2n8yW7wNwUQ3mOJkoie5kqlPal6OmaPgh7BzS.pdf
para el componente livewire:

componente create:

```
$archivo_pdf = $this->pdf->store($path_file_pdf, 'public');
    $archivo_nom = $this->pdf->getClientOriginalName();
```

componente index:

```
public function export(Manual $manual)
{
    $carpeta = substr($manual->archivo_pdf, 0, 7);
    $search = "/";
    $replace = "\\";
    $new_sentence = str_replace($search, $replace, $manual->archivo_pdf);
    return Storage::disk('public')->download($new_sentence);
}
```

el index:

```
@foreach ($manuales as $manual)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                                {{ $manual->archivo_nombre }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">

                                <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                                    <div class="inline-flex shadow-md hover:shadow-lg focus:shadow-lg" role="group">
                                        
                                        <a  wire:click="export({{$manual->id}})" download="{{$manual->archivo_nombre}}"
                                            target="_blank"
                                            class="inline-block px-3 py-2.5 font-bold cursor-pointer text-xs leading-tight hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-gray-100 bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 border duration-200 ease-in-out border-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-gray-800 transition"
                                            title="Descargar manual">
                                            <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
                                        </a>

                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Al descargar se va con el nombre grabado por laravel, yo quiero hacer como cambiarlo por el nombre del archivo original.

Comment: `return response()->download($pathToFile, $name);`. Está explicado en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#file-downloads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es no cambiar el nombre del archivo al almacenarlo, en su lugar crea una carpeta con nombre único donde se almacenara únicamente este archivo con su nombre original, así cada archivo almacenado estará en su propia carpeta y conservaran su nombre para descargar. Lo que sugiero se mira así:

```
$filename = $this->pdf->getClientOriginalName();
$path = "archivos/".uniqid()."/{filename}"; 
Storage::put($path,$path_file_pdf);
```

Se almacenaría en storage/archivos/CARPETA/ARCHIVO.EXTENSION

Tendrías la ruta del archivo en $path para almacenarla
y traerías el archivo de esta manera:

```
return response()->download(storage_path($path));
```